# How to display data from database into Kendo Grid

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, kendo-grid

I want to display my data from database to kendo grid but the result is no display. I don't know what happen can you see correct my code if there's wrong syntax for display my data into kendo grid. I try so many solution but my problem is still the same and here is my Code in Controller

```
namespace TBSWebApp.Controllers
{
public class LoanApplicationController : Controller
{
    // GET: LoanApplication
    public ActionResult LoanApplication()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public static List<DisplayRecords> objCmp = new List<DisplayRecords>();

    static LoanApplicationController()
    {
        string strServer = GlobalVariable.prServer;
        string strDatabase = GlobalVariable.prDatabase;
        string mainconn = string.Format(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BackendEntities"].ConnectionString, strServer, strDatabase);
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string s1 = "SELECT InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,FileAs,LoanBalance FROM tblInvoice LEFT OUTER JOIN tblContacts ON tblInvoice.CustomerID = tblContacts.ContactID WHERE LEFT(InvoiceNo,2) ='LR'";
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(s1);
        sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn;
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        List<DisplayRecords> objmodel = new List<DisplayRecords>();
        if (sdr.HasRows)
        {
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                objCmp.Add(new DisplayRecords { InvoiceNo = sdr["InvoiceNo"].ToString(), InvoiceDate =Convert.ToDateTime(sdr["InvoiceDate"].ToString()), FileAs = sdr["FileAs"].ToString(), Amount = sdr["LoanBalance"].ToString() });

            }
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
    }
    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
     {
        var result = objCmp.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
        return Json(result);
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, DisplayRecords person)
    {
        if (person != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var toUpdate = objCmp.FirstOrDefault(p => p.InvoiceNo == person.InvoiceNo);
            TryUpdateModel(toUpdate);
        }


        return Json(ModelState.ToDataSourceResult());
    }
}
}
```

and this is my code in view  LoanApplication.cshtml for my design in kendo grid

```
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:100%;height:100%">
              @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TBSWebApp.Models.DisplayRecords>().Name("LoanApplication")
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.InvoiceNo))
                                .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "LoanApplication"))
                                .Update(up => up.Action("UpdatePerson", "LoanApplication"))
                        )

                        .Columns(columns =>
                        {
                            columns.Bound(c => c.InvoiceNo).Width(200);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.InvoiceDate);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.FileAs);
                            columns.Bound(c => c.Amount);
                            columns.Command(cmd => cmd.Edit());
                        })

                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("Person"))
    )
</div>
```

and i don't think if there is wrong with my code in here . Can you enlighten me if I have something to config in some other settings, not just in controller and view and the below is the image of the result

[image]

and the below is my data from sql server:

[image]

Comment: Gunna ask the obvious question, does `result` in `GetData` actually have anything in it?

Comment: @JamesS yes it has i put a breakpoint and it shows 8 records result